# Transition period, for certificates in WSS Java

Tags: java, keystore

I have a certificate set up for WSS encryption, in a Java server. Its referenced by org.apache.wss4j.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=old_cert.
This certificate expires soon, and I have therefore issued a new. Can I set up a transition keystore and config, with both the old and new certificate, such users can migrate now, before the expiration date?